# getting StreamCorruptedException

Tags: android, sockets, object, client, outputstream

I am trying to stream an `ObjectOutput`, but i get the error above.

**CODE:**

```
private void writelogin(int i, int j, int k, int c4, int l, int m, Socket sock) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ObjectOutputStream dos = new ObjectOutputStream((OutputStream)sock.getOutputStream());
    boolean data = true;
    int[] btw = new int[]{i,j, k, c4, l, m};

    do {
        ((ObjectOutput) dos).writeObject(btw);
            data=false;
        } while (data);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();}}
```

I have no clue why.

The exception is outet via `System.out` not via `Errorlog`.

**What my Server receives:**  AC ED (sometimes a lot of 00 and other hexa 'seem-random' numbers)

**What my Stream has to send:** 03 96 144 54 79 05

**what my Server has to receive:** 03 60 90 36 4F 05

that hexadecimal numbers are permitted is correct, so not the problem.

Problem is there, since i use `ObjectOutputStream` and an `Array`, as i used `DataOutputStream` and put every block itself via `dos.writeByte(i);dos.writeByte(j);` it worked fine.

figured something new out: my `ObjectOutputStream` sends an `AC ED 00 05` on his own... does anyone know how to avoid that? I´m sending nothing, but he does.

Doesn't matter anymore, found a way to work around. Figured out that it is even possible to send an Array via `DataOutputStream`, so this is avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the same ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream for the life of the socket, at both ends, rather than creating one or the other every time you need one of them.

Comment: i do this, but the output and input are in different methods, may this cause the problem?

Comment: @Ekonion No, you *don't* do this. Look at your code. You create a new one every time you call the method. I have no idea what your question means.

Comment: NOW i got it... thx alot, i think it will be easy-ongoing now ^^ sry for taking your time.... but one question is left: if i only creat one of each (input and output) how do i access them from another acivity? or do i have to close the socket everyt5ime i sent sth and received sth?

Comment: @Ekonion Save them as members of whatever class you are saving the Socket in.

Comment: in cause of being new to java and android im not exactly sure what a member is. is it a subclass that extends the main class e.g. `private class DOS extends SockClass{` ?

Comment: What do you mean "at both ends"? How are server and client supposed to use the same object?

Answer (score 0):

Following code looks suspicious:

```
((ObjectOutput) dos).writeObject(btw);
```

Simply try,

```
dos.writeObject(btw);
```

Why are you typecasting and that too to ObjectOutput?

EDIT: I think you are forgetting `new` in your array initialization.

```
int[] btw = new int[]{i,j, k, c4, l, m};
```

Comment: deletet what you mention, but still the same... i had a cast there too, because eclipse said i need one there before. Now it's away and eclipse seems to be okay with it, but my problem still exists.

Comment: Ok. Also, I think you are forgetting 'new' in your array initialization. See my edit.

Comment: addes ^^ looks more logical now, but still the same... will add a small explaination in my Q

Comment: You are correct that the cast is redundant, but removing it doesn't actually change anything, and doesn't therefore solve this problem or answer this question.